# applyNativeModulesAppBuildGradle(project) and applyNativeModulesSettingsGradle in gradle kts file

Tags: android, react-native, kotlin, gradle-kotlin-dsl

I am using the Gradle KTS file and trying to set up the React native. I am not able to add

applyNativeModulesAppBuildGradle(project)

What is the alternative for `applyNativeModulesAppBuildGradle` in KTS. Also on settings, we have to write `applyNativeModulesSettingsGradle`

Comment: did u resolve this problem :( I meet the same issue like u

Answer (score 4):

Things may have changed. For recent RN Android projects, use this:

```kotlin
import groovy.lang.Closure
import org.gradle.api.Project

apply(from = "../node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-android/native_modules.gradle")
val applyNativeModules: Closure<Project> = extra.get("applyNativeModulesSettingsGradle") as Closure<Project>
applyNativeModules(settings)

include(":app")

includeBuild("../node_modules/@react-native/gradle-plugin")
```

---

Below is my solution，calling `applyNativeModulesSettingsGradle` method in `native_modules.gradle`:

```
import groovy.lang.Closure

apply(from = "../node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-android/native_modules.gradle")
val applyNativeModules: Closure<Any> = extra.get("applyNativeModulesSettingsGradle") as Closure<Any>
applyNativeModules(settings)
```

Use the Kotlin way to get the method reference from extra, then invoke the function.

Comment: This might have worked in the past, but on the latest versions of React Native I get the following error message: `Could not get unknown property 'preBuild' for root project 'reactNativeTestCli' of type org.gradle.api.Project.`