# How to apply applyNativeModulesSettingsGradle inside a settings.gradle.kts

Tags: android, react-native, gradle, build.gradle, gradle-kotlin-dsl

I'm integrating React Native in an Android app which is already in production. I'm using react-native 0.66.5 and it's almost working. The only problem is that my gradle is using Kotlin and not Groovy as the majority... so my struggle is:

I need to apply the following code in my `settings.gradle.kts`, but how can I do that using Kotlin?

```
apply from: file("../node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-android/native_modules.gradle"); applyNativeModulesSettingsGradle(settings)
```

[React-Native Docs](https://reactnative.dev/docs/0.66/integration-with-existing-apps#enable-native-modules-autolinking)

I already tried a few solutions like the followings but still not able to make the autolink work...

```
apply(from = file("./node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-android/native_modules.gradle"))
```

and

```
val applyNativeModulesSettingsGradle: () -> Unit = {
    val nativeModulesGradleFile = File("./node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-android/native_modules.gradle")
    if (nativeModulesGradleFile.exists()) {
        apply(from = nativeModulesGradleFile)
    } else {
        throw GradleException("native_modules.gradle not found in @react-native-community/cli-platform-android.")
    }
}

applyNativeModulesSettingsGradle()
```

Comment: Check with this thread if its works: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64368918

Comment: @BogdanKushhlus the solution listed there is not working for me. Maybe it doesn't work any longer due to a change in the external file.